# WSManCredSSP setting cannot be enabled

Tags: hyper-v, remote, hosts

Im trying to set up 2 Hyperv 2016 Server hosts on my local network for remote access, but I just cant get them going.

Servers are configured properly - both running:

- PSRemoting (also tried -skipnetworkprofilechecking)
- Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server, even the firewall is turned off

Computer is configured accordingly:

- Edited the Hosts file, can ping both servers
- Added them to trusted hosts list
- In gpedit added wsman/myhost in both Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials policies.
- Configured COM Security to allow all

**The problem is that I cant execute this cmdlet - Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer "my host"**

It returns **This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled.**
And when I try to connect either of hosts it returns CredSSP authentification is currently disabled on the local client. But when I run **winrm get winrm/config** it shows that CredSSP is True. I believe, that CredSSP is on, because while ago I was managing another host, and it was working just fine.

Yesterday when I tried to connect via different computer it gave me the same CredSSP error, but I Could run the Enable-WSManCredSSP Command. The difference was that when I tried to connect the host via Hyper-V manager I got Enable Credential Delegation box in loop. When I restarted host and client it again showed the CredSSP error.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a missing configuration on server, that im missing? The Remote Desktop is working fine, but I need to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix my issue. I just completely stopped the winrm process, deleted all listeners and started it again. The delegatecomputer command executed successfully. Now I can connect to all my hosts with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way
I was working on this problem almost two weeks and now I know that sometimes you can have problem with command Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer "my host"

That is because command has not access for registry editing even you running powershell as administrator. I think it's Microsoft bug and I will create ticket for MS Support

However there is workaround and you can do it by this script

https://github.com/bolvua/Enable-WSManCredSSP